# corresponding CSS filter attributes for Konva filter(Brightness, contract, Saturation, value)

Tags: javascript, css, konvajs

I have a use-case to draw high-quality images preview with some dynamic filters(Brightness, contrast, Saturation, value), as the image quality is so high, I can't use Konva directly. I have tried original images with css Filter which is performant. is there any way to map Konva filter value to CSS filter attributes.

e.g.
image.contrast(aa) =>  css filter contrast(bb)